# Defining a Scheme function

Tags: scheme

So i have been stuck trying to learn this Scheme language that i heard about from a friend of mines. What he said i should do is start small and work my way up to truly understanding it. So after reading a textbook that he had that discusses Scheme programming briefly, i am a little puzzled myself on how it works.

So pretty much what i am trying to ask is that if i wanted to add a definition to a function called, let's say 'evens' from a couple of list i have define:

```
(DEFINE list0 (LIST 'j 'k 'l 'm 'n 'o 'j) )
(DEFINE list1 (LIST 'a 'b 'c 'd 'e 'f 'g) )
(DEFINE list2 (LIST 's 't 'u 'v 'w 'x 'y 'z) )
(DEFINE list3 (LIST 'j 'k 'l 'm 'l 'k 'j) )
(DEFINE list4 (LIST 'n 'o 'p 'q 'q 'p 'o 'n) )
(DEFINE list5 '((a b) c (d e d) c (a b) )
(DEFINE list6 '((h i) (j k) l (m n)) )
(DEFINE list7 (f (a b) c (d e d) (b a) f) )
```

such that it does like the task below: evens

which I have already created a adder function which i believe is to be:

```
(DEFINE (adder lis)
    (COND
        ((NULL? lis) 0)
        (ELSE (+ (CAR lis) (adder (CDR lis))))
))
```

**what might the definition for even be if i would want it to do like the task below:**

EVENS:
(evens 1st) should return a new list, formed  from the the even numbered elements taken 1st.

```
(evens '(a b c d e f g))
which would/should return:
(b d f)
```

and:

```
(evens (LIST 's 't 'u 'v 'w 'x 'y 'z))
which would/should return:
(t v x z)
```

and:

```
(evens '(f (a b) c (d e d) (b a) f) )
which would return:
((a b) (d e d) f)
```

and both (evens '()) and (evens '(a))

would return the empty list.

I have been going through trail in error to practice but i am totally lost. Thanks in advance

Okay, I think that i have come up with a recursive function to my example that i have been trying to work out:

```
 (define mylist '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7))
 (define (evens lst)
 (define (do-evens lst odd)
     (if (null? lst)
 lst
     (if odd
         (do-evens (cdr lst) #f)
         (cons (car lst) (do-evens (cdr lst) #t)))))
         (do-evens lst #t))
```

any thoughts?

Comment: You should try not to capitalize anything really, there is no need for it and as far as I know most compilers do not even allow you to do that.

Comment: @Jordan until R6RS, Scheme implementations were not case sensitive.  Many scheme implementations have shunned R6RS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so to do a recursive function that iterates over a list, picking some elements to return and not others, the basic pattern is going to be

```
(define (recur l)
  (cond
    ((null l) '())
    ((??????) (cons (car l) (recur (cdr l))))
    (else (recur (cdr l)))))
```

What that does is

1. Is the list null?  Return null.
2. If the list is not null, should we be keeping the first item on the list?  Ok, let's keep it and add it to whatever `(recur (cdr l))` returns
3. Otherwise, just return whatever `recur (cdr l)` returns.

What I hope this makes clear is that a simple recursive list function only looks at the first element of the list, determines what do do with that and then calls itself again with the remainder of the list.  Recursion is, in one sense, a way of simplifying computation by only dealing with the first part of the data and leaving another function to worry about the rest of the data (the *other* function is actually the same function you called the first time, but try not to worry about that). For example, a recursive function which only returned the items which were even numbers could look like this:

```
(define (even-numbers l)
  (cond
    ((null? l) '())
    ((even? (car l)) (cons (car l) (even-numbers (cdr l))))
    (else (even-numbers (cdr l)))))
```

That said, your case is slightly more complex; you need to drop the first element and then, in each successive call to the function, do the opposite of the last call.

One way to to this is to pass on a boolean status, flipping it each time.  Note that since the **evens** function doesn't take state, you have to define a different internal function and recur on that:

```
(define (evens l)
  (let loop ((lst l) (keep #f))
      (cond
         ((null? lst) '())
         ((eq? keep #t) (???????)
         (else (loop (cdr l) #t)))))
```

You should be able to work out what goes in `(???????)` for yourself, given the previous examples.  I've done a little too much work for you, I think.

Another way to do this is with mutually recursive functions *evens* and *odds*.  Consider that

1. **evens** is a function that throws away the first element and then works through the list, each time doing the opposite (keep or discard) of what it did last time.
2. **odds** is a function that keeps the first element and then works through the list, each time doing the opposite (keep or discard) of what it did last time.

This means that you could define

1. **evens** as a function that ignores the first element and simply calls **odds** on the remainder of the list.
2. **odds** as a function that keeps the first element, calls **evens** on the remainder of the list and **cons**-es the first element onto the beginning of the result.

That would look something like

```
(define (evens l)
  (cond
    ((null? l) '())
    (else (odds (??????)))))

(define (odds l)
  (cond
    ((null? l) '())
    (else (cons (car l) (evens (??????))))))
```

Hopefully, this makes some sense.

If you really want to understand recursion in Scheme, buy a copy of "The Little Schemer" and start working through it.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the `adder` function has nothing to do with your question, right?

Think about the `evens` function. You have already said that `(evens '())` and `(evens '(a))` should return the empty list.  What should `(evens '(a b))` return?  What about `(evens '(a b ...))`?  Do you see how to set up the recursion?

Comment: I do not see how the recursion is set-up sorry. But i think is (evens '(a b)) would return 'b' right?

Comment: Right. Now write that in scheme.  And then write (evens '(a b c)) in terms of (evens '(a b)).

Comment: Sorry i think the reason why i am confused is because i do not see how to set up the recursion.

Comment: Well, you did set up the recursion in your adder function...  In that function your base case is when `lis` is empty.  In this case your base case is a bit more complicated: an empty list, a list with 1 element, or a list with two elements.  So you will have a `cond` statement with 4 conditions.

Comment: Thank You now i think i am starting to see the idea.

Comment: @user1786512 You can drop that down to 3 conditions, one of which is **else**, with some thought.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
(define (evens l)
  (cond
   ((null? l) '())
   ((null? (cdr l)) '())
   (else (cons (cadr l) (evens (cddr l))))))
```

But I like the evens and odds answer!